Cardinal of a set of integers with symmetry relations
Context
In computational chemistry, there are two-electron integrals noted $(ij|kl)$ for integers (i,j,k,l) between 1 and K. The explicit expression of $(ij|kl)=\int dx_1dx_2 \chi_i(x_1)\chi_j(x_1)\chi_k(x_2)\chi_l(x_2)$ where $\chi_i$ are some functions.
These integrals have the following symmetry relations:

$(ij|kl)=(ij|lk)$ (1)
$(ij|kl)=(ji|kl)$ (2)
$(ij|kl)=(kl|ij)$ (3)

How many unique integrals are there?
The solution for $K=100$ is $12753775$.
Attempt to reformulate the problem
I tried to reformulate the previous problem as the following:
Find the cardinal of the set: $S=\\{ (i,j,k,l)/ (i\leq j) \land (i\leq l) \land (l\leq k) \land (j\leq k) \\}$
To exclude the duplicates defined by (1) and (2), I only take integrals with $i\leq j$ and $k\leq l$. To eleminate duplicates in the sense of (3), I only take elements with $i\leq l$ and $j\leq k$.
For $K=100$, I computed $\sum_{i=1}^K\sum_{j=1}^K\sum_{l=j}^K\sum_{k=i}^l 1$. But I get $8670850$ unique integrals which is not the solution.
What I am missing? Also, is there a more elegant proof?

There are $\frac {K(K+1)}2$ pairs of $i,j$ and the same number of pairs of $k,l$.  This accounts for the first two symmetry relations.  To account for the third we have $\frac 12 \left(\frac {K(K+1)}2\right)\left(\frac {K(K+1)}2 +1\right)$ pairs of pairs.  For $K=100$ this gives $\frac 12(5050 \cdot 5051)=12753775$

But the pairs $i,j$ where $i=j$ are not taken into account.

Yes, they are.  That is why it is $K(K+1)/2$ instead of $K(K-1)/2$.  The difference is the $K$ pairs with $i=j$  Try it with $K=2$ where this predicts three pairs, $11,12,22$
